# Get-ADUser unable to connect to AD LDS instance

Tags: powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7-x64, adlds

I installed [AD LDS on Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14683), created an instance and created a user with ADSI Edit as described [here](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/07/12/getting-started-with-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services.aspx), but when I try to access it with `Get-ADUser -Server Win7Box -Filter *` I get this error:

> Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.

I tried from the Windows 7 box and from a Windows 2008 R2 box and got the same error in both cases.

Is the Windows 7 AD LDS fully featured? do you have any clue?

Comment: Does the Windows Firewall allow access to port 389? Does something listen on port 389?

Comment: yes, `netstat -a` shows that something listen on port 389 and no, Windows FW does not block port 389 (I can query AD LDS local instance with `ldp`)